# Java Android - Send data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I've been trying to figure out how to pass data from `Activity` to a `Fragment` for the past day and haven't gotten very far. I know how to pass data from `Fragment` to `Activity` though. I don't think I can use a bundle for my situation because my `Fragment` will have already been created and will need to continue to listen to `Activity` for any changes. I've also tried creating an interface but I get some cyclic error. It was very easy for me to pass data from `Fragment` to Activity, I feel like I'm overthinking how to pass data back from `Activity` to `Fragment`.

[image: image description here]

This is a simple version of what I'm trying to do. `Activity` is on top and the bottom buttons are from the `Fragment` layout.

When I click on BTN1 from `MainActivity`, I would like button TESTBTN 1A to change to the color red and store i = 1. Then button TESTBTN 1B will change to green and i = 2. And button TESTBTN 1C will change to blue and i = 3. When NEXT FRAGMENT is clicked, it will take the `Fragment` to the next one (and hopefully not lose the button color changes).

**Here's the main part of my `MainActivity`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Main2Activity.OnDataPass{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}


public void onClickBtn1(View v){
    //need to send data over to fragment1 to be stored and to change color
}

public void onClickBtn2(View v){
    //need to send data over to fragment1 to be stored and to change color
}

public void onClickBtn3(View v){
    //need to send data over to fragment1 to be stored and to change color
}

public void onClickBtn4(View v){
    //go to next fragment
}

//used for when fragment passes data to activity
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG", "passed data: " + data);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Main2Activity(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main3Activity(), "TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main4Activity(), "TAB3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**and here is my `Fragment`**

```
public class Main2Activity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {
int i;
Button btnTESTa, btnTESTb, btnTESTc;     
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2,container,false);
    btnTESTa = view.findViewById(R.id.btnTESTa);
    btnTESTb = view.findViewById(R.id.btnTESTb);
    btnTESTc = view.findViewById(R.id.btnTESTc);

    btnTESTa.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTESTb.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTESTc.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

//NEED TO CREATE A WAY TO LISTEN FOR DATA SENT OVER FROM ACTIVITY TO CHANGE BUTTON COLORS AND STORE INT I VALUE

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnTESTa:
            i = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.btnTESTb:
            i = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.btnTESTc:
            i = 2;
            break;
    }

    passData(String.valueOf(i));
}

//used to pass data over from fragment to activity
OnDataPass dataPasser;

public interface OnDataPass {
    void onDataPass(String data);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}

public void passData(String data) {
    dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
}
```

And here is my SectionsPageAdapter
    public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
```

Any help on how I can achieve sending data from my `Activity` to `Fragment` to change the button color is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the Fragment instance in your Activity code? Why can't you just call methods on that Fragment? Remove the ViewPager for now. it's only complicated things

Comment: You can create a public method in your fragment and call that using fragment instance you created.

Comment: By the way, `Main2Activity extends Fragment`, is not an Activity. Please fix your class naming conventions if you want others to understand the code

Comment: why are you complicating things for this simple task just use an interface and pass the id for respective button click and accordingly change the color inside your fragment

Comment: @cricket_007 Just added the Fragment instance... or at least what I think it is. Sorry, just started learning about Fragments, still a little confused of everything

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela do you have a link to how I can do that by any chance?

Comment: Create a setter method for dataPasser in Main2Activity and call that method from MainActivity and pass context to that.

Comment: @sumit I've tried that but then I get a cyclic inheritance error. I'm probably not doing it right though

Comment: @SagarPujari do you have an an example by any chance? That sounds like it could work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your code is OnDataPass instance has to be created in your Activity and not Fragment as you want to pass data from Activity to Fragment and not Fragment to Activity.

So sample code block for Activity and Fragment classes will be like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnDataPass{

          MyFragment fragmentInstance;



          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              fragmentInstance = new MyFragment();
          }

          private void loadMyFragment(){
             fragmentInstance = new MyFragment();
             //code to load fragment

          }

      public void passData(String data) {
         if (fragmentInstance != null) fragmentInstance.dataFromActivity(data);
      }

      @Override
          public void onDataPass(String data){
             //handle data and do the needful. Instead of String you can even use bundle here.
          }
    }
```

So as i mentioned in my comment, have created a public method named `dataFromActivity` which you can call from Activity class to pass data from your Activity to Fragment.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
       OnDataPass dataPasser;

       public interface OnDataPass {
            void onDataPass(String data);
       }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
    }

    @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();

            dataPasser = null;
    }

    public void passData(String data) {
        if (dataPasser != null) dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
    }

        //method called from Activity
        public void dataFromActivity(String data){
            //handle data and do the needful. Instead of String you can even use bundle here.
        }
    }
```

Fragment will user `OnDataPass` interface to send data from Fragment to Activity.

Comment: I actually do want to pass data from Fragment to Activity. But I also want to pass data from Activity to Fragment as well. Seems like a very simple task but I can't figure it out

Comment: Check the modified code, now you can do both i.e. can pass data from Activity to fragment and fragment to activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

**Main2Activity.java**

```
 public class Main2Activity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {
 .......

   //method to change button background at run time.
   public void changeButtonColor(View view){
      switch(view.getId()){
      case R.id.btnTESTa:
          btnTESTa.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
           i = 1;
          break;
      case R.id. btnTESTb:
          btnTESTb.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
           i = 2;
          break;
      case R.id. btnTESTc:
          btnTESTc.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
           i = 3;
          break;
      }
   }
 ........
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Main2Activity.OnDataPass{

  .........

  private Main2Activity fragment2;
  private Main3Activity fragment3;
  private Main4Activity fragment4;

  public void onClickBtn1(View v){
      fragment2.changeButtonColor(v);
  }

  public void onClickBtn2(View v){
      fragment3.changeButtonColor(v);
  }

  public void onClickBtn3(View v){
      fragment4.changeButtonColor(v);
  }

  public void onClickBtn4(View v){
       //fragment transaction code here
  }

  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
      .......
      fragment2 = new Main2Activity();
      fragment3 = new Main3Activity();
      fragment4 = new Main4Activity();

        adapter.addFragment(fragment2, "TAB1");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment3, "TAB2");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment4, "TAB3");
        .......
   }
   .......
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add setter method in Main2Activity as below

```
 public void setDataPasser(OnDataPass dataPasser) {
    this.dataPasser = dataPasser;
}
```

Then call this setter method in MainActivity.
Then update the following method in your MainActivity:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
Main2Activity fragment = new Main2Activity();
fragment.setListener(this);
adapter.addFragment(fragment, "TAB1");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to communicate between `activities` and `fragments`, however, the usage you give them is based on the requirements for your app. 
If the data is needed for `Fragment` initialization, you can pass it using the `newInstance` method of every `fragment` as parameter or parameters.
If you need to pass data in `runtime`, you need to use an `interface`, which is going to initialize in the `onAttach` method of every fragment using the activity `Context` and going null every time he fragment gets destroyed.
To summarize on the second option, you need to:

1. Declare an `interface`, most likely inside the `fragment` you're working on.
2. Declare a global variable of the `interface`'s type.
3. Initialize the variable in the `onAttach` method of the fragment.
4. Nullify the variable in the `onDestroy` method.
5. Call the interface methods in the buttons you want.
6. Implement the `interface` in the `activity` and handle the callback methods.